# Reading file during LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, class, enums

I have a simple class, and I want to have the results from:
(which are correct so far)

```
            Console.WriteLine(f.temp1);
            Console.WriteLine(f.temp2);
```

in my Class Definitions temp1=Name; temp2=id

```
public class Definitions
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        ReadDefinitions();
    }

    public static void ReadDefinitions()
    {
        var files = from name in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Settings.Folder)
                    from id in File.ReadLines(name).Skip(2).Take(1)

                    select new
                    {
                        temp1= Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name),
                        temp2= id

                    };

        foreach (var f in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f.temp1);
            Console.WriteLine(f.temp2);
        }

        foreach (var f in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f.temp1);
            Console.WriteLine(f.temp2);
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is stupid with this temp stuff, but I could not manage to do it directly. :(

The goal is to:

- Read the directory with many thousand files...
- Put the name into Definitions.Name
- Put line 3 of every file into Definitions.Id

So that I can access them anytime in my Program.

(I still need to trim the 3 left characters of line AND the 4 right characters of it,..but I'll probably manage that myself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If understand correctly you just need to do this

```
    var files = from name in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Settings.Folder)
                select new
                {
                    temp1= Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name),
                    temp2= File.ReadLines(name).Skip(2).First()
                };
```

If you want to skip the temp stuff then you can:

```
    var files = from name in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Settings.Folder)
                select new Definitions 
                {
                    Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name),
                    Id = File.ReadLines(name).Skip(2).First()
                };
```

Comment: `File.ReadLines` is just fine. I think you had in mind `File.ReadAllLines`.

Comment: naaaah.....this is obvious. I wanna have it in my Class Descritions.Name and Descriptions.Id and have acces to it in my main programm

Comment: Ivan is right, I confused it with ReadAllLines. So your code is ok. I will ammend now